# Корректно ли наследование классов?

Tags: python, ооп, python-2.x

Я использую в проекте такую структуру:

```
CleanMaster
  - Libs
    - programclass
      - __init__.py
      - ShowScreens.py
    - main.py
    - program.py
```

**main.py** - выполняется при старте приложения и просто импортирует основной класс программы **Program** из модуля **program.py**

В пакете **Libs/programclass** я держу классы, которые наследую в классе **Program**.

Пример архитектуры класса **Program** модуля **program.py**:

```
from Libs import programclass as program_class  # классы программы


class Program(program_class.ShowScreens):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Program, self).__init__(**kvargs)

        # Теперь мне доступны все атрибуты и методы класса ShowScreens.
        self.attribute_class_program = True
```

Код файла **__init__.py** из пакета **Libs/programmclass**:

```
from .ShowScreens import ShowScreens
```

Пример архитектуры класса **ShowScreens** модуля **ShowScreens.py** из пакета **Libs/programmclass**:

```
class ShowScreens(object):
    # Здесь мне доступны все атрибуты и методы класса Program,
    # которые упомянуты в его конструкторе через ключевое слово self.
    print self.attribute_class_program
```

Вопрос: насколько корректен такой подход?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что имеется ввиду под корректностью. Мне кажется, если в Вашем проекте это работает, и вас устраивает, то значит — корректно. 
Не очень понятно, причем тут наследование классов. Или вы про организацию модулей и классов? Я лично, использую аналогичную технику, для удобного разбиения пакеты на модули.

*Меня немного смущает, что вы не придерживаетеcь PEP8.*

Comment: Что значит, "не придердиваюсь"?! Придерживаюсь!

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names цитата: «Modules should have short, **all-lowercase names**. […] Python packages should also have short, **all-lowercase names**, [...]».

Comment: Да? Пусть это почитает Гвидо ван Россум с его IDLE! :D

Comment: Полагаю, это как историческое наследие. Кажется, что IDEL появился до введения этого правила. Аналогичная проблема с [logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993667/how-come-the-pythons-logging-module-doesnt-follow-pep8-conventions). + Я не утверждаю, что вы делаете что-то плохое, просто меня это  немного смущает.

Comment: Я делаю так, как удобно именно мне! Кажется, это также прописанно в PEP8. Открывая любой "официальный" модуль, вы можете увидеть такие вырвиглазные нарушения стандарта, что "all-lowercase names" - это просто цветочки.